# When we need to call - (AWSTask *)refresh which will backend to fetch token and identity id

Tags: ios, iphone, aws-sdk-ios

As the token will get expired in one hour and we need to fetch new token, I want to know will be allocating cumstomIdentityProvider class again or thers is another ay of doing that. Need help.

This is i have implemented in My cumstomIdentityProvider.

```
- (AWSTask *)refresh {
    /*
     * Get the identityId and token by making a call to your backend
     */
    // Call to your backend

    // Set the identity id and token
    self.identityId = IdentityId;
    self.token = Token;
    return [AWSTask taskWithResult:self.identityId];
}
```